# How to select a column value in to a case statement for a result of another column in the same table

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, stored-procedures

This is a very simplified vision of the statement

```
SELECT  
    ChangeId,
    ColumnName,
    BeforeChange,
    CASE ColumnName 
       WHEN 'x' THEN AfterChange ELSE 'dbo.function(Y)' 
    END AS AfterChange,
    AfterChangeUpdateId,
    UpdatedBy,
    ChangeDate,
    ChangeType
FROM 
    [DEV].[dbo].[tblperson_Audit]
```

Not sure this is possible but I want to pass the `ColumnName` value in to the `CASE` statment to show different results depending upon the value for every row.

The function passes a value for an integer.

Any help would be great thanks

Comment: thanks but not passing column name in to the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this? It is assumed that the function returns single value

```
SELECT  ChangeId,
ColumnName,
BeforeChange,
CASE ColumnName WHEN 'x' THEN AfterChange ELSE dbo.function(ColumnName) END AS AfterChange,
AfterChangeUpdateId,
UpdatedBy,
ChangeDate,
ChangeType
FROM [DEV].[dbo].[tblperson_Audit]
```

Comment: the result of that is just to run the function every time, Im not passing the column name in to the function i am passing an integer from the afterchange column ELSE dbo.function(audittablename.afterchange) END

Comment: thanks just got this working not sure how i missed it!

Answer (score 0):

Slight syntax error in Madhivanan's solution. It should be:

```
case when condition() then column1 else column2 end as columnname
```

So in your example:

```
CASE WHEN 'x' THEN AfterChange ELSE 'dbo.function(Y)' as AfterChange
```

SQL Server's conditional syntax always seems so counter-intutive and weird I have to Google it every time...